# HSQL & Atomikos: unsupported internal operation: Result

Tags: grails, hsqldb, atomikos

I have a Grails application configured to use the Atomikos plugin in order to connect to two databases. When I try to update both databases in a transaction, I get the following exception:

```
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: connection exception: connection failure:  java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Result
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource.prepareThis(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource.prepare(Unknown Source)
at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.prepare(XAResourceTransaction.java:622)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.PrepareMessage.send(PrepareMessage.java:61)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.PropagationMessage.submit(PropagationMessage.java:111)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator$PropagatorThread.run(Propagator.java:87)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator.submitPropagationMessage(Propagator.java:66)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.prepare(ActiveStateHandler.java:173)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.prepare(CoordinatorImp.java:832)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.terminate(CoordinatorImp.java:1159)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.commit(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:92)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:236)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.commit(TransactionManagerImp.java:498)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction.commit(J2eeUserTransaction.java:104)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1010)
```

Can anyone shed some light why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question on the HSQL Help forum. It seems that in HSQL 2.3.1, remote XA transactions were not implemented yet, but they will probably be in the next release.

Here is the link to [the forum thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/3b217629/).